# Running java apps in a chroot **without** /proc mounted

Tags: java, chroot

I'm trying to build a java application (invoking javac) in a chroot environment where /proc is NOT mounted. Javac hangs after spitting out the following warning:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Can't detect initial thread stack location - find_vma failed

I don't know if this warning is related to the hanging, but it's consistently being logged. I looked at the jvm source code, and I can understand what this warning is about (/proc/self/maps is not available when trying to find the main thread's stack base).

It should be noted that sometimes i'd get a crash instead of hanging, but it hangs most of the time.

I was wondering if anyone got java to work **without** /proc mounted. All the available literature suggests mounting /proc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that in general you would want /proc mounted in your chroot environment... In general in Linux /proc is used for process information and information about the system that is useful to various processes. The JVM does a lot of "Magical" things because it's acting as well, a virtual machine, and so it needs a lot of information about processes and things it's doing, so it's not surprising that it would not work without proc.

From what I've read about how OpenJDK's JVM works, for Unix(like) systems they use procfs to get information. So it seems like it would be mandatory.

Is there a reason you think you don't want /proc?

Comment: The reason why I can't have /proc mounted is that the build team in my company wants to build packages in a chroot with minimal dependencies on the environment. I guess if the JVM doesn't support running without /proc mounted i'll have to convince them to mount /proc.

Comment: Also while browsing through the jvm source code, I saw comments and code to handle cases when /proc is not mounted (in a chroot), so i'm guessing the jvm implementation at least "intended" to work without /proc..

Comment: I wouldn't really consider proc much of a dependency since procfs is itself built into the kernel. I mean you can get it up by doing mount -t proc proc /mnt/jail/proc

I was checking into some FreeBSD OpenJDK related threads on forums talking about Java's behavior without the BSD procfs module loaded, and bad things pretty much are reported to happen. Which kind of confirms my suspicions.

Comment: I can attest to the bad things happening.. Thanks for checking other threads. I feel i'll have to convince them to allow proc to be mounted. I also found out that other standard tools rely on proc mounted as well. For example, the dynamic loader relies on /proc/self/exe to resolve $ORIGIN references in the RPATH. So this is not something too much to require in my opinion. It should be clearly documented in the jvm though that running without proc is not supported

Comment: Yeah this isn't a big ask in any way shape or form... It's not asking for software to be installed, it's something that could easily be included in their jail provisioning script in one line. It's your ops team being a pain because they can. Some ops teams do that...